# div content flowing into other div

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/nwq3v3t2/1/

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#footer-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    /* top: 2px; */
    /* left: 2px;
    right: 2px; */
    text-align: right;
    font: bold;
}

.hp_wgt_row {
    min-width: 33.33%;
    min-height: 33.33%;
    height: 33.33%;
    /* border: 2px black solid; */
    position: relative;
}

.hp_wgt_col {
    min-width: 33.33%;
    min-height: 33.33%;
    height: 33.33%;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.hp_wgt_header {
    background-image: linear-gradient( 45deg, blue, red );
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 23px;
    padding: 2px 12px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.hp_wgt_content_wrapper {
    /* position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden; */
    min-height: 200px;
}

.hp_wgt_content {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 3px auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.hp_wgt_circular_ul {
    /* height: 90%; */

}

.hp_wgt_circular_ul li {
    color: black;
}

.hp_wgt_circular_ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
/* .hp_wgt_circular_ul li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: blue;
} */
```

```html
<div style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 95%;">          
            <div class="row hp_wgt_row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Circular</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content_wrapper">
                        <div class="hp_wgt_content">
                            <ul class="list-group hp_wgt_circular_ul">
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 1 Circular 1 Circular 1 Circular 1 Circular 1 Circular 1 Circular 1</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 2 Circular 2 Circular 2 Circular 2 Circular 2 Circular 2</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 3</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 4</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 5</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 6</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Logo</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Login</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row hp_wgt_row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Phone Database</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Photo Gallery</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">News</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row hp_wgt_row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Links</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Events</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Others</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The list overlaps with the bottom div. I tried a fixed height and overflow but the scrollbar looks horrible and on browser fullscreen, there is a gap between the divs. What I need is that the content inside .hp_wgt_content should maintain height and overlapping discipline no matter the screen size.

I am a complete noob at web designing.

Comment: Can you show the design you want ?

Comment: You may need to use some jquery plugin like this [http://masonry.desandro.com/](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: @yashpandey If you will please check the fiddle and expand the output panel, the content under circular heading flows into the phone database header. I need the content to stay inside .hp_wgt_content .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on what output you want to display. Try removing the `height` from your `.hp-wgt-row` class because these makes it overlap. Only focus on `width` if you want to make it responsive on other screen sizes.

Update:

I returned back the height from the `.hp_wgt_row` and added `overflow-y: scroll`. Then I removed the height on the `.hp_wgt_col` instead to make it not overlap.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#footer-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    /* top: 2px; */
    /* left: 2px;
    right: 2px; */
    text-align: right;
    font: bold;
}

.hp_wgt_row {
    min-width: 33.33%;
    min-height: 33.33%;
    height: 33.33%;
    /* border: 2px black solid; */
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.hp_wgt_col {
    min-width: 33.33%;
    min-height: 33.33%;
    /* height: 33.33%; */
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.hp_wgt_header {
    background-image: linear-gradient( 45deg, blue, red );
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 23px;
    padding: 2px 12px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.hp_wgt_content_wrapper {
    /* position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden; */
    min-height: 200px;
}

.hp_wgt_content {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 3px auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.hp_wgt_circular_ul {
    /* height: 90%; */

}

.hp_wgt_circular_ul li {
    color: black;
}

.hp_wgt_circular_ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
/* .hp_wgt_circular_ul li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: blue;
} */
```

```html
<div style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 95%;">          
            <div class="row hp_wgt_row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Circular</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content_wrapper">
                        <div class="hp_wgt_content">
                            <ul class="list-group hp_wgt_circular_ul">
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 1 Circular 1 Circular 1 Circular 1 Circular 1 Circular 1 Circular 1</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 2 Circular 2 Circular 2 Circular 2 Circular 2 Circular 2</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 3</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 4</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 5</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Circular 6</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Logo</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Login</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row hp_wgt_row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Phone Database</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Photo Gallery</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">News</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row hp_wgt_row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Links</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Events</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hp_wgt_col">
                    <div class="hp_wgt_header">Others</div>
                    <div class="hp_wgt_content">Circular</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: If I remove the height and add more elements .hp_wgt_content, the row takes the height of hp_wgt_content. I need all three rows to have equal heights.

Comment: Which class do you remove the height? Can you provide an updated jsFiddle on your work?

Comment: I removed the height from .hp_wgt_row

Comment: Is it possible to have a fixed height for hp_wgt_content with a hidden scrollbar and also have the height responsive to fit multiple screen sizes?

Comment: What you mean by all three rows to have equal heights is the `.hp_wgt_row` has the same all sizes? If in that matter, how about try giving it a constant height and use `overflow`.

Comment: For the height, it doesn't matter, I guess, since users tend to scroll vertically. So focusing on the page's width is needed for adaptable screen size.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the inline style height:100% on top most div and make it "auto". it will fix the issue